# Django ManyToManyField relationships

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models

Leagues, Teams and Players

League Model have :

```
teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', null=True, blank=True)
```

yes, a Team can play in more than one League

Team Model have :

```
players = models.ManyToManyField('Player', null=True, blank=True)
```

a player can play in more than one Team

When I submit a player I need to tell the system which team he will play and which league but I couldn include the League Field on the admin of Player Model.

I would like to do something like this

```
class LeagueInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = League.teams.through
    extra = 3

class TeamInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Team.players.through
    extra = 3

class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        TeamInLine,
        LeagueInLine
        ]

admin.site.register(Player, PlayerAdmin)
```

but as there no direct relationship between PLayer and League it throws me an error

Comment: I think your relations are wrong. You don't need a direct relation from the player to the league. You can find each league for a player by following the relations from PLAYER over TEAM to LEAGUE.

Comment: I tried to do it but I couldnt put it on the admin.

For example I can make 
`class TeamInLineForPlayers(admin.TabularInline):
    """
    Team List for Player admin
    """
    model = Team.players.through
    extra = 3 `

but I dont know how to follow to the League

Comment: The model that has the relation to both are Team, so you can use Team as the "main" admin model and inline the others.